# Launch PowerPoint on MAC OS from Java Swing App in Fullscreen Mode

Tags: java, macos, swing, powerpoint, fullscreen

I'm attempting to create a java swing application that runs in fullscreen mode, that can launch powerpoint presentations in fullscreen mode on top (in front) of my application, and then when they end, return to my application.

I build a JFrame and launch it this way:

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(myFrame);
```

To launch the powerpoint presentation, I have a button that calls an applescript that tells powerpoint to open a presentation file and run it.  That works, but the presentation appears only for a second before the swing application takes over again and shows on the screen.  Further button clicks don't seem to bring the presentation back to the front.

The desired behavior:

1. User clicks on the presentation to open.
2. The presentation opens, "on top" of the application.  When the end is reached, the presentation exits presentation mode.
3. The presentation has exited, so the swing application is again the foremost fullscreen window.

I'd really like to understand what is happening behind the scenes, but it's hard to even know what to search for on Google.  If anyone could even point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

UPDATE 1

As I'm new to this forum, I'm following RealSkeptics advice on editing this post with new information instead of adding comments.  I will leave my current comments but will edit going forward.  Anyway, on with the update:

I tried switching my swing frame to be maximized and "always on top" instead of full screen mode. Unfortunately, the "always on top" setting places it above (in front of) the PowerPoint presentation in presentation mode.  If I could get this behavior to change, this solution would probably work for me.

UPDATE 2

I have been thinking about Mac OS' "Spaces" (virtual desktops).  Many programs, when putting things into Fullscreen mode through the menu's "Enter Fullscreen Mode", create a new Space for that window.  Entering mission control will show the normal desktop, plus another Space for the new fullscreen program.  PowerPoint in presentation mode, however, doesn't go into a new Space, it goes over the current desktop.  I have not had a chance to enter mission control with the Swing app in fullscreen mode to see what happens, but will post an update when I do.

I'm wondering about potentially trying to get presentations launched from my application to open in a new Space.  I don't yet understand exactly how spaces work in the context of Mac OS' windowing systems, but I'm hoping that each space could potentially have something in fullscreen, and the newest would always show until closed, at which point the new Space would be destroyed and the normal desktop would be returned to, with the swing application still in fullscreen exclusive mode.

Comment: Are you sure the Powerpoint presentation is opened in Fullscreen mode?

Comment: Yes.  I see it launch, and then when I close the swing app and click to give focus to powerpoint, it is in full screen presentation mode.

Comment: I tried switching my swing frame to be maximized and "always on top" instead of full screen mode.  Unfortunately, the "always on top" setting places it above (in front of) the PowerPoint presentation in presentation mode.  Can anyone give any details on how PowerPoint works in presentation mode in MAC OS?  I'd like to understand how Microsoft coded it.

Comment: Tip: edit your question, and add the additional information that you collected. An edit pushes the question to the main page where more people have a chance of seeing it. Also, you may ask non-programming questions such as "How does powerpoint work on the MacOS in presentation mode" on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).